# How to trace if database become inaccessible in Spring-boot application

Tags: java, database, spring-boot

I have a Spring-boot desktop application with a few database connections. If the main database is not accesible application can't work. Is there any solution to trace connection failures to notificate user?

I have tried this

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            Application.launch(args);
        } catch (java.net.ConnectException e) {
                    //user notification code
        }
}
```

But I can't single out main database Exceptions because stack
trace does not contain database specific information.

Another guess I have is to run simple query by timer. This solution demands a lot of useless requests. Is it appropriate?

Comment: I would say that its quite common to do some trivial query on a regular interval to check the health status. For Web I would go for Spring Actuators but I doubt whether they would be a great fit for a desktop application.

Comment: You can try one of these solutions : https://www.onlinetutorialspoint.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-actuator-database-health-check.html